# Optimization of program processing structured input for large data

Tags: c, optimization, large-data

I have this one task. To make it more clear, I am gonna use picture below as an example. Input and output is separated with dotted line. First line of input is number **N** - number of sets. For every set, it's first line are 2 numbers - first one declares how many numbers am I gonna process and second one is number of intervals. Second line specifies the numbers to process and third line contains 2 numbers **X** and **Y**, which create and interval. For every interval I have to output 3 numbers - lowest number on interval, index of highest number on interval and XOR of all numbers. Everything is running fine except it is really slow for big data and I have no idea how to make work faster. I have attached my code and large data input as well.

[input.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wil1utvcfyapvj3/input.txt?dl=0)

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
  int id;
  int index;
} Censor;


int Xor(const int x, const int y, const Censor array[]) {
  int xor = array[x].id;
  if (x == y) {
    return xor;
  }
  for (int i = x + 1; i <= y; i++) {
    xor ^= array[i].id;
  }
  return xor;
}

int int_cmp(const void *a, const void *b) { 
    const Censor *ia = (const Censor *)a; 
    const Censor *ib = (const Censor *)b;
    return (ia->id  - ib->id); 
} 

int LowestId(const int x, const int y, Censor array[]) {
  int id = array[x].id;
  if (x == y) {
    return id;
  }
  qsort(array, y - x + 1, sizeof(Censor), int_cmp);
  return array[0].id;
}

int HighestIdIndex(const int x, const int y, Censor array[]) {
  int index = array[x].index;
  if (x == y) {
    return index;
  }
  qsort(array, y - x + 1, sizeof(Censor), int_cmp);
  return array[y].index;
}

int main() {
  int t, n, q, b, e;
  int max = 100;
  int count = 0;
  int *output = (int *)malloc(max * sizeof(output));
  scanf("%d", &t); //number of sets
  for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &q);
    //I am making 3 separate arrays for numbers, because some of them are being sorted and some of them not
    Censor lowest_id[n];
    Censor highest_id_index[n];
    Censor xor[n];
    //This loop fills arrays with the numbers to be processed
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      scanf("%d", &(lowest_id[j].id));
      lowest_id[j].index = j;
      highest_id_index[j].id = lowest_id[j].id;
      highest_id_index[j].index = j;
      xor[j].id = lowest_id[j].id;
      xor[j].index = j;
    }
    // Now I am scanning intervals and creating output. Output is being stored in one dynamically allocated array.
    for (int k = 0; k < q; k++) {
      scanf("%d %d", &b, &e);
      if (count + 3 >= max) {
        max *=2;
        int *tmp = (int *)realloc(output, max * sizeof(tmp));
        if (tmp == NULL) {
          return 1;
        } else {
          output = tmp;
        }
      }
      output[count++] = LowestId(b, e, lowest_id);
      output[count++] = HighestIdIndex(b, e, highest_id_index);  
      output[count++] = Xor(b, e, xor);
    }
  }
  printf("---------------------\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", output[i]);
  }
  free(output);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have two calls of qsort. Maybe you could do with one

Comment: Since you only need to find the (value or position) of the smallest and the largest, then you can do with no calls to qsort. A simple linear pass will do.

Comment: To be honest I didn't really find the correlation between the input and the output but let's assume that you are right and the output is as expected. Why do you need to *sort* the sub arrays? Min/Max detection can be performed by passing through the relevant subarray in O(n). Sorting in most of the cases is much more complicated, O(n*log(n)) and higher.

Comment: Yeah, I don't even know, why I was attempting to sort, when I don't need it. Thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Dan Mašek and @Alex Lop.  Sorting subarray in this case was unnecessary. Much easier is to iterate through the subarray in linear complexity.